# Offset drop-down menu in IE7

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, internet-explorer-7

I'm having some issues with a drop-down menu in IE7.
It works fine in all other browsers but appears offset in IE7 for some reason. Any ideas?
Please see the menu code below and the computed CSS from Firebug as well as images demonstrating the issues.

Correct Menu
[image: Correct Menu]

Offset Menu
[image: Offset Menu]

HTML

```
<ul id="coolMenu">
 <li class="">
    <a class="donate" href="#">
        User Options
        <span class="downarrowclass"></span>
    </a>

    <ul id="style_me" style="display: none;">
        <li>
            <a href="#">Candidate Panel</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Access details</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Personal details</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">History</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Withdraw application</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Jobs by e-mail</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Log off</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
#coolMenu,
#coolMenu ul {
   list-style: none;
}
#coolMenu {
   float: right;
}
#coolMenu > li {
   /*float: left;*/
}
#coolMenu li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
color: #ffffff;
width: 100px;
text-align: center;
}
#coolMenu ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    z-index: 999;
}


#coolMenu li:hover ul {
display: block;
}

.dropdown a li{
color: #124162 !important;
}

#coolMenu li #style_me  li  a{
color: #124162 !important;
width: 140px !important;
}

#coolMenu li #style_me  li  a:hover {
color: #ffffff !important;
}
```

If it helps, there appears to be some form of offset present in the IE developers tab:
[image: IE developers tab]

Also, here is the computed code in iedeveloper for ul coolmenu.
[image: ie developer]

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle so we can mess with the code?  Also, is the li only offset on hover?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be fixed by targeting IE7 specifically using the following code:

```
Html.ie7 #coolMenu ul {
top: 59px;
left: 71px;
}
```